# Iterative search on secondary dataframe to return values ​to primary dataframe new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I have two dataframes - df1 & df2. I need to search each value from a specific column in df1 on df2 and return 2 nearest values.

```
data1 = np.array([(1, 150), (2, 250), (3, 350), (4, 590)])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['n', 'day'])

df1
    n   day
0   1   150
1   2   250
2   3   350
3   4   590
```

```
data2 = np.array([(120, 10.5), (180, 10.7), (350, 11.2), (620, 15.5)])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['day', 'rate'])

df2
    day rate
0   120 10.5
1   180 10.7
2   350 11.2
3   620 15.5
```

I managed to find the values using this function:

```
#to find 2 nearest values
def find_rates(df, s, x, n=2):
    diff = (s - x).abs()
    return df.loc[diff.nsmallest(n).index].sort_index()
```

Exemple:

```
find_rates(df2, df2.day, 150, n=2)

         day    rate
0   120.0   10.5
1   180.0   10.7

find_rates(df2, df2.day, 350, n=2)
     day    rate
1   180.0   10.7
2   350.0   11.2
```

What I expect from this is to iterative search each "day" value from df1 on df2 and store 2 nearest values on df1 new columns:

```
data3 = np.array([(1, 150, 120, 180, 10.5, 10.7), (2, 250, 180, 350, 10.7, 11.2), (3, 350, 180, 350, 10.7, 11.2), (4, 590, 350, 620, 11.2, 15.5)])
want = pd.DataFrame(data3, columns=['n', 'day', 'day1', 'day2', 'rate1', 'rate2'])
want
     n  day     day1    day2    rate1   rate2
0   1.0 150.0   120.0   180.0   10.5    10.7
1   2.0 250.0   180.0   350.0   10.7    11.2
2   3.0 350.0   180.0   350.0   10.7    11.2
3   4.0 590.0   350.0   620.0   11.2    15.5
```

Any clues on how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possible solution :

```
N = 2

day1 = df1["day"].to_numpy()[:, None]
day2 = df2["day"].to_numpy(); arr2 = df2.to_numpy()
idx = np.sort(np.argsort(np.abs(day2 - day1), axis=1)[:, :N])

days  = pd.DataFrame(arr2[:, 0][idx], columns=["day1",  "day2"])
rates = pd.DataFrame(arr2[:, 1][idx], columns=["rate1", "rate2"])

out = pd.concat([df1, days, rates], axis=1)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   n  day   day1   day2  rate1  rate2
0  1  150 120.00 180.00  10.50  10.70
1  2  250 180.00 350.00  10.70  11.20
2  3  350 180.00 350.00  10.70  11.20
3  4  590 350.00 620.00  11.20  15.50
```

Answer (score 4):

You can modify your function to return a Series:

```
def find_rates(df, s, x, n=2):
    diff = (s - x).abs()
    out = (df.loc[diff.nsmallest(n).index]
             .sort_index(ignore_index=True)
             .unstack()
          )
    out.index = out.index.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]+1}')
    return out

out = df1.join(df1['day'].apply(lambda x: find_rates(df2, df2.day, x, n=2)))
```

For a vectorial approach, you can use [`numpy.argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html):

```
a1 = df1['day'].to_numpy()[:, None]
a2 = df2['day'].to_numpy()

n = 2
idx = np.argpartition(abs(a1-a2), n)[:, :n]

df1[[f'day{x+1}' for x in range(n)]] = df2['day'].to_numpy()[idx]
df1[[f'rate{x+1}' for x in range(n)]] = df2['rate'].to_numpy()[idx]
```

Output:

```
   n  day   day1   day2  rate1  rate2
0  1  150  120.0  180.0   10.5   10.7
1  2  250  180.0  350.0   10.7   11.2
2  3  350  180.0  350.0   10.7   11.2
3  4  590  350.0  620.0   11.2   15.5
```

Comment: First approach didnt work as espected but the second one did! Tks!

Comment: @Jorge can you explain how the first approach didn't work?

Comment: When i run the code i get "out" with day3 and rate3 extra columns and "nan" to day1 and rate1 second register (actualy, the values for this row are in day3 and rate3).

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use KDTree from sklearn.neighbors.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
"""
to sort neighbors by 'day' value:
"""

data1 = np.array([(1, 150), (2, 250), (3, 350), (4, 590)])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['n', 'day'])

data2 = np.array([(120, 10.5), (180, 10.7), (350, 11.2), (620, 15.5)])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['day', 'rate'])
"""
print(df1)

   n  day
0  1  150
1  2  250
2  3  350
3  4  590
print(df2)
     day  rate
0  120.0  10.5
1  180.0  10.7
2  350.0  11.2
3  620.0  15.5
"""


tree = KDTree(df2[['day']])
"""
reshape(-1, 1) transforms the 1D array into a 2D array.
"""
day_values = df1['day'].values.reshape(-1,1)
"""print(day_values)
[[150]
 [250]
 [350]
 [590]]"""
 
"""
The KDTree doesn't return the actual data of the neighbors directly. 
Instead, it provides indices that point to where 
those neighbors are located in the original DataFrame (df2).

k=2: Specifies that you want to find the 2 nearest neighbors for each 'day' value.
return_distance=False: Indicates that you only need the indices of the neighbors, not their distances.
indices is a 2D NumPy array that holds the indices of the nearest neighbors found by the KDTree
"""
 
indices = tree.query(day_values,k=2, return_distance=False) 
" Type : 2D NumPy array. Shape: (8, 2) # 8 neighbors, 2 columns"
neighbors1 = df2.iloc[indices.flatten()].values

"""print(neighbors1) 
[[180.   10.7]
 [120.   10.5]
 [180.   10.7]
 [350.   11.2]
 [350.   11.2]
 [180.   10.7]
 [620.   15.5]
 [350.   11.2]]"""
 
"""
Type: 3D NumPy array.Shape: (4, 2, 2) # 4 rows in df1, 2 neighbors per row, 2 values per neighbor 
Extracting 'day' and 'rate' values from nearest neighbors
"""
neighbors = df2.iloc[indices.flatten()].values.reshape(indices.shape + (-1,))
"""print(neighbors) 
[[[180.   10.7]
  [120.   10.5]]

 [[180.   10.7]
  [350.   11.2]]

 [[350.   11.2]
  [180.   10.7]]

 [[620.   15.5]
  [350.   11.2]]]
"""

"""
Now SORTING

But for that You must Find the indices that would 
sort the 'day' values (column 0) within each row (axis=1) 
of the 3D neighbors array in ascending order.
np.argsort directly returns the indices that would sort the array 
in ascending order.
neighbors[:, :, 0] selects a specific portion of the 3D array
:, :, 0: Focuses on the first column (index 0) of all rows and columns within that array.
:, :, 0 has three colons, corresponding to the three dimensions of a 3D array:
The first colon (:) selects all elements along the first dimension (rows).
The second colon (:) selects all elements along the second dimension (columns).
The final part, 0, specifies that only the first column (index 0) 
should be considered within this selection. 

np.arange(len(indices)) creates an array with numbers from 0 to the length of indices minus 1
np.arange(len(indices))[:, None] selects all rows of neighbors.
sorted_indices specifies the order in which columns should be rearranged within each row.
[:, None] is like adding an extra column to the table with placeholder values, 
making it compatible for advanced column-wise operations.
"""
sorted_indices = np.argsort(neighbors[:,:,0],axis=1)

neighbors = neighbors[np.arange(len(indices))[:,None],sorted_indices]
"""
print(neighbors)
[[[120.   10.5]
  [180.   10.7]]

 [[180.   10.7]
  [350.   11.2]]

 [[180.   10.7]
  [350.   11.2]]

 [[350.   11.2]
  [620.   15.5]]]

"""

day1,day2 = neighbors[:,:,0].T
"""
print(day1)
[120. 180. 180. 350.]
print(day2)
[180. 350. 350. 620.]
"""
rate1, rate2 = neighbors[:, :, 1].T
"""
print(rate1)
[10.5 10.7 10.7 11.2]
print(rate2)
[10.7 11.2 11.2 15.5]
"""


for i in range(1, 3):  # Iterate for day1, day2, rate1, rate2
    df1[f'day{i}'] = neighbors[:, :, 0][:, i - 1]  # Assign day values
   
    df1[f'rate{i}'] = neighbors[:, :, 1][:, i - 1]  # Assign rate values
   
 
"""print(df1) 
   n  day   day1  rate1   day2  rate2
0  1  150  120.0   10.5  180.0   10.7
1  2  250  180.0   10.7  350.0   11.2
2  3  350  180.0   10.7  350.0   11.2
3  4  590  350.0   11.2  620.0   15.5
"""
```